# MacOS Flutter: ld: can't write output file for architecture x86_64

Tags: flutter, macos

It was working yesterday, know it doesn't work and I don't know why.
It's a simple flutter project running on macOS.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in my_project...
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
Building macOS application...
ld: can't write output file: /Users/username/IdeaProjects/my_flutter_project/my_project/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/my_project.app/Contents/MacOS/my_project for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
** BUILD FAILED **

Exception: Build process failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo rm -rf build`

I found out that I generated files that I wasn't allowed to write anymore...

But it's generated files so we can delete them all and everything works fine !

Comment: I had created a build with VScode in SU mode - later on moving back to user mode, got this error. flutter clean and flutter pub get did the job!